# Polygon data cannot be imported into MySQL, but MultiPolygon data can

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

I can’t figure out why this doesn’t work (throws a "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field”):

```
UPDATE Table
SET Shape = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[[-39.440918,-11.113727],[-23.972168,4.981505],[-21.862793,-29.477861],[-39.440918,-11.113727]]]
}')
WHERE Id = 6
```

and this does:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Shape = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{
    "type": “MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [[[[-39.440918,-11.113727],[-23.972168,4.981505],[-21.862793,-29.477861],[-39.440918,-11.113727]]]]
}')
WHERE Id = 6
```

Doesn’t matter if I use GeoJSON or WKB, the results are the same.

What’s the difference between Polygon and MultiPolygon structures and why the first one is not accepted and the second one is?

Running MySQL 5.7.19.

Answer (score 1):

My fault, column type was set to MULTYPOLYGON. But what confused me is that there were other rows set as Polygon. I suppose it was caused by a server update from 5.1 to 5.7. Perhaps 5.1 lets you store a Polygon in a MultiPolygon column.